# CSS Button Unknownly Centered

Tags: html, css, button, center

Alright, I've got a button that I can't figure out why in the heck it's centring itself. My first suspicion was in the css, but any sort of `align` or `position` that I used/changed didn't work.

Here's the html and css. You'll probably be able to find it faster than I would.
(Also here's the jsfiddle link if anyone's interested: http://jsfiddle.net/takkun/63uktgyo/)

```css
/* ROUNDED ONE */
.Gcheckbox {
/*CHANGES GRAY SQUARE DIMENSIONS*/
 width: 16px;
 height: 33px;
 background: #ff0000;
 
 /*GRAY SQUARE BACKGROUND FADER*/
 background: linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 0000ff 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
 margin: 0px auto;
 
 position: relative;
}

.Gcheckbox label {
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;

/*MAKES THE GREEN CIRCLE A CIRCLE*/
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
/********************************/

 left: 3px;
 top: 11.25px;

 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1), 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1), 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1), 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1);

 /*BEHIND GREEN CIRCLE BACKGROUND*/
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
 background: linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0000ff', endColorstr='#0000ff',GradientType=1 );
}

.Gcheckbox label:after {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 background: #00bf00;

 background: linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);

 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 bottom: 0px;
 right: 0px;

 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #00ff00, 0px 0px 0px rgba(42,171,43);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #00ff00, 0px 0px 0px rgba(42,171,43);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #00ff00, 0px 0px 0px rgba(42,171,43);
}

/*CHANGE HOVER EFFECT OPACITY*/
.Gcheckbox label:hover::after {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=30);
 opacity: 0.3;
}

.Gcheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 opacity: 1;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
 visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleCIRCLE.css" type="text/css">
 <title>custom checkbox testing</title>
    </head>
<body>


<!--styleCIRCLE -->
<div class="Gcheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="Gcheckbox" name="check" />
   <label for="Gcheckbox"></label>
  </div>
  


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is horizontally centered because the containing parent, `.Gcheckbox` has left and right automatic margins, which has the effect of horizontally centering the element.

By removing or commenting out that line, we will have the element aligning to the left as per default left-to-right layout behavior.

```css
/* ROUNDED ONE */
.Gcheckbox {
  /*CHANGES GRAY SQUARE DIMENSIONS*/
  width: 16px;
  height: 33px;
  background: #ff0000;

  /*GRAY SQUARE BACKGROUND FADER*/
  background: linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, 0000ff 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #000000 100%, 0000ff 0%, #ff0000 0%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
  /*margin: 0px auto;*/

  position: relative;
}

.Gcheckbox label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;

  /*MAKES THE GREEN CIRCLE A CIRCLE*/
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  /********************************/

  left: 3px;
  top: 11.25px;

  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1), 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1), 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1), 0px 0px 0px rgba(239,239,238,1);

  /*BEHIND GREEN CIRCLE BACKGROUND*/
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #0000ff 0%, #0000ff 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0000ff', endColorstr='#0000ff',GradientType=1 );
}

.Gcheckbox label:after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #00bf00;

  background: linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #00ff00 0%, #00ff00 100%);

  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #00ff00, 0px 0px 0px rgba(42,171,43);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #00ff00, 0px 0px 0px rgba(42,171,43);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #00ff00, 0px 0px 0px rgba(42,171,43);
}

/*CHANGE HOVER EFFECT OPACITY*/
.Gcheckbox label:hover::after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.Gcheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="Gcheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="Gcheckbox" name="check" />
  <label for="Gcheckbox"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the margin: 0px auto; on your .Gcheckbbox div.

Remove that and it's all fine and dandy :)

Comment: Oh my god I'm so dumb and I love you. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. You can get a bit lost when looking at big chunks of code too long.